# Sanitize dynamically loaded IronPython script against malicious code

Tags: c#, security, unity-game-engine, ironpython, python-2.6

I'm making a game in Unity and I want to max out configurability - user can load his own packages with own levels, textures, sound effects, AI behaviour etc. For the AI part I'm aware it's probably not quite possible without scripting, so I was looking for way to dynamically load & run scripts from already built Unity game. I managed to do that via IronPython but I'm worried that someone may use this feature to create fake packages, that run malicious code on player's computer. I think I should impose some restrictions on what kind of code can be run (which functions used? which modules imported?) but I have no idea even where to start. I've never done anything like that before. All I can google is things like sanitizing HTML or GET/POST queries **using** Python... not quite what I want, as I want to sanitize **Python itself**.

Here's test sample of how I'm launching Python:

```
public class PythonLauncher : MonoBehaviour
{
    ScriptEngine engine;
    ScriptScope scope;

    void Start()
    {
        engine = Python.CreateEngine();
        scope = engine.CreateScope();

        scope.SetVariable("foo", new Foo { someExampleData = "World" });

        string example = "output = 'Hello ' + foo.someExampleData + '!'";
        var source = engine.CreateScriptSourceFromString(example);
        source.Execute(scope);

        var output = scope.GetVariable<string>("output");
        Debug.Log(output);
    }
}

public class Foo
{
    public string someExampleData;
}
```

So to sum up, I'm looking for at least some hints. Where to begin?

**EDIT:**

OK, I googled some more, because I noticed, how similar it is to using `eval()` in python... Sanitizing `eval()` showed up some more views. Now I have some ideas what to watch out for but:

1. I don't know whether it's a complete list of what wrongs can be done?
2. I still don't know anything about technical side; how to inspect code to check for some disallowed tokens or anything... compilation/parsing/tokenization/etc. is a black magic for me.

What have I found is e.g.:

- https://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/159393-sanitizing-untrusted-code-eval
- https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/uny12/eval_really_is_dangerous/